# input string in bio python via sys.argv

Tags: python, sys

I want to give a string stored in a txt file as an argument to a python code via sys.argv command. This is the code called script.py

```
import sys
seq = sys.argv[1]
print seq
```

and this is the string stored in seq.txt:
AAABBBCC

Now when I run

```
python script.py seq.txt
```

I get

```
seq.txt
```

as output. How can I get it to print the string in seq.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

You need to open the file like this before you can read it and print it.

Comment: See also [PEP-0278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) for using `'rU'` as an alternative for only `'r'` as a parameter in `open()`. This is more general.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your file to read its contents.

When you do this:

`seq = sys.argv[1]`

You are simply getting the string value of what you are providing to your script arguments.

What you want to do is take `seq` and get the contents of the file by doing something like this:

```
fi = ""
with open(seq) as f:
    fi = f.readlines()
```

You will probably need to do some more things after that, but I'll leave that to you. :)

Read up on Python files here: [Python Files](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

What if you read the file into a variable first, and then passed it to python?

```
$ my_var=$(<text_file.txt)
$ python python_file.py "$my_var"
```

Comment: That actually sounds more like what the OP was asking come to think of it. @Ssank is this what you were looking for?